# Using Parameter values as Operators in SQL AND Clause

Tags: sql, t-sql

Trying to understand how to use the following query (extracted from Dynamic SQL) to use in normal compiled SQL code.

```
and sub_agg.TotalSubmissions ' + @Operator + N' ' + convert(nvarchar,@Value) + N'
```

The @Operator (has values such as <,>,>= etc) and the @Value is an integer value.

So the query should return for example; and sub_agg.TotalSubmissions > 1

No matter how I change the syntax, it reports that the syntax is incorrect

Comment: You've got the `+` on the wrong side of your quotes. For example, it should be `TotalSubmissions + @Operator + N' ' + convert(...`

Comment: Also, this won't execute as you'd expect (it'll return rows of strings). You'll need to wrap it in `exec` (for SQLServer, not sure about other flavours) and pass it the SQL text

Comment: Thanks for the response. So what should I be including as the full string as I am still getting some syntax troubles

Comment: Ok thanks for update.

Comment: It's hard to give you an exact answer, as the query suddenly begins with `and` which is already a syntax error in itself. Are you wanting it to return a string as an answer? In that case my first comment pretty much fixes it all (plus remove the final `N'`)

Answer (score 0):

You can make dynamic query like this :

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand varchar(1000)
DECLARE @Value varchar(75)
DECLARE @Operator varchar(75)
SET @Operator = '>'
SET @VALUE = '2'
SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT sub_agg.TotalSubmissions FROM TotalSubmissions WHERE sub_agg.TotalSubmissions' + @Operator + convert(nvarchar,@Value)
EXEC (@sqlCommand)
```